# How to set up SFTP server that doesn't affect entire machine

Tags: sftp

I set up chrooted SFTP directories on a RHEL 8 server that also has several websites running on it. When I tried to ssh in this morning, the server said it only accepts SFTP connections. Fortunately, it's a VM so I can connect directly to the console.

Here's what I added to `sshd_config` on Friday:

```
ForceCommand internal-sftp
Match Group sftpusers
ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u
```

Commenting out the `ForceCommand` line gets me back in via ssh. What's the correct directive to constrain SFTP users to a directory without turning the entire server into an SFTP server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at `man sshd_config`, the documentation writes:

> **`ForceCommand`** - Forces the execution of the command specified by `ForceCommand`, ignoring any command supplied by the client

By specifying `ForceCommand internal-sftp` you are telling `sshd` that every ssh connection must execute `internal-sftp` regardless of what the client requests or expected.

You almost certainly meant to use `Subsystem`, which is documented as follows:

> **`Subsystem`** - Configures an external subsystem (e.g. file transfer daemon).

To correct your situation, remove the entry for `ForceCommand` and replace it with `Subsystem`. I also tend to indent commands after a `Match` or `Host` line to make it visually clearer that they apply only if the `Match` or `Host` applies.

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match Group sftpusers
    ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you!